# How do I find element in array object and update source array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to find element in target array and update in the source array.

```
let sourceArray = [
  {
    "userId": "123",
    "applicationId": "abc",
    "selections": [
      {
        "applicationId": 70930,
        "creationDate": "2021-01-28",
        "responseStatus": "PENDING"
      }
    ]
  }
]

let array2 = [
  {
      "applicationId": 70930,
      "code": "TEST CODE",
      "creationDate": "2021-01-28",
      "submissionDate": "2021-01-29",
      "status": "SUBMITTED",
      "outcomeStatus": "PENDING",
      "responseStatus": "PENDING"
  }
]
```

My expected outcome is selections to get updated in source array with matching elements from array2 based on applicationId

```
[
  {
    "userId": "123",
    "applicationId": "abc",
    "selections": [
      {
        "applicationId": 70930,
        "code": "TEST CODE",
        "creationDate": "2021-01-28",
        "submissionDate": "2021-01-29",
        "status": "SUBMITTED",
        "outcomeStatus": "PENDING",
        "responseStatus": "PENDING"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried updating the array using code below

```
const newArray = sourceArray.map(item => {
  let item2 = array2.find(i2 => item.selections.some(id => i2.applicationId === id.applicationId));
  return item2 ? { ...item, ...item2 } : item;
});
```

Comment: So if `array2` has `creationDate` equal to `2021-02-01`, will it override what's in `sourceArray`?

Comment: Yes it will update the sourceArray

Comment: I have updated my attempt, I keep getting back, it should go in selections.

[{
  "userId": "123",
  "applicationId": 70930,
  "selections": [
    {
      "applicationId": 70930,
      "creationDate": "2021-01-28",
      "responseStatus": "PENDING"
    }
  ],
  "code": "TEST CODE",
  "creationDate": "2021-01-28",
  "submissionDate": "2021-01-29",
  "status": "SUBMITTED",
  "outcomeStatus": "PENDING",
  "responseStatus": "PENDING"
}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this. Just remember to keep track of other info when destructing

```js
let sourceArray = [
  {
    userId: "123",
    applicationId: "abc",
    selections: [
      {
        applicationId: 70930,
        creationDate: "2021-01-28",
        responseStatus: "PENDING",
      },
    ],
  },
];

let array2 = [
  {
    applicationId: 70930,
    code: "TEST CODE",
    creationDate: "2021-01-28",
    submissionDate: "2021-01-29",
    status: "SUBMITTED",
    outcomeStatus: "PENDING",
    responseStatus: "PENDING",
  },
];

sourceArray = sourceArray.map(({ selections, ...otherInfo }) => ({
  ...otherInfo,
  selections: selections.map((selection) => ({
    ...selection,
    ...array2.find((el) => el.applicationId === selection.applicationId),
  })),
}));

console.log(sourceArray)
```